# Would this type of question be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

### INTRODUCTION AND RELEVANT INFORMATION:

I have a desktop application with a window that needs to display large amount of entry fields. Please take a look at below image:

[image]

As indicated on the image, controls in the red rectangle should be in main window, other ones can be shown when needed, using progressive disclosure/tabs/etc. I have used purple line to mark related groups of data.

I am using WPF and XAML to create GUI.

### MY EFFORTS TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM:

I have tried to break that content into tabs, in order not to clutter the GUI.

I have placed controls from red rectangle into main window, docked them left and then added tab control next to the map. Everything else was placed into appropriate tabs ( groups marked with purple line on the above image ).

### PROBLEM:

My problem is that layout can not be fully seen on small laptops despite "breaking" the window into tabs. Since the screen is divided into 3 columns map can not fit properly, it is just a thin vertical line.

I would like to ask here for help, in view of GUI redesign so it can fit into small laptop screens. I am not targeting tablets/phones.

### QUESTION:

Is this type of question on topic for this site?

*IMPORTANT: I can provide detailed description of every field from the above mockup. I have mockups of the tabs as well (my own effort to solve the problem).*

Comment: Side note: titles already have a rather strong emphasis. Please don't also make them ALL CAPS on top of that.

Comment: @Mat: OK thank you for your constructive criticism. I usually post questions in above format, and that proved so efficient. I will try it with your advice in the future posts. Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this type of question on topic for this site?

No, probably not. Your question is more about UI/UX as opposed to programming.

[UX.SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) would be a better place for you because you are asking for *help, in view of GUI redesign so it can fit into small laptop screens*.

> User Experience Stack Exchange is for User Experience Designers,
>   Information Architects, and Human Computer Interaction researchers. If
>   you have a question about...
>
> - Specific UX design problems
> - UX issues that can be solved with expert advice or existing research
> - Questions about HCI and user research

Comment: Thought so... Thank you.